# Index a 2D Numpy array with 2 lists of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a strange situation.

I have a 2D Numpy array, x:

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0,5,(20,8))
```

And I have 2 indexers--one with indices for the rows, and one with indices for the column.  In order to index X, I am having to do the following:

```
row_indices = [4,2,18,16,7,19,4]
col_indices = [1,2]
x_rows = x[row_indices,:]
x_indexed = x_rows[:,column_indices]
```

Instead of just:

```
x_new = x[row_indices,column_indices]
```

(which fails with: error, cannot broadcast (20,) with (2,))

---

I'd like to be able to do the indexing in one line using the broadcasting, since that would keep the code clean and readable...also, I don't know all that much about python under the hood, but as I understand it, it should be faster to do it in one line (and I'll be working with pretty big arrays).

---

Test Case:

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0,5,(20,8))

row_indices = [4,2,18,16,7,19,4]
col_indices = [1,2]
x_rows = x[row_indices,:]
x_indexed = x_rows[:,col_indices]

x_doesnt_work = x[row_indices,col_indices]
```

Comment: Include a sample case?

Comment: Nitpick: `np.random.randint(0, 6)` is perferred to `np.random.random_integers(0, 5)`.

Comment: And the expected output for that case?

Comment: What is your expected result? Are you trying to get all elements in columns 1, 2 of the selected rows?

Comment: `x_indexed` is what I am expecting...so, I need the rows according to the indices, at the columns specified by the column indices.

Comment: try this: `x_new = x[row_indices,:][:,col_indices]`

Comment: @bordeo. The variable name of what you are expecting is not relevant. It's the contents that was confusing us.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh, I meant it like, if you run the code, the values within x_indexed are what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first try would work if you write it with np.newaxis

```
x_new = x[row_indices[:, np.newaxis],column_indices]
```

Comment: I think, you might need to change row[column]_indices into np.array.

Answer (score 58):

### Selections or assignments with `np.ix_` using indexing or boolean arrays/masks

#### 1. With `indexing-arrays`

**A. Selection**

We can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to get a tuple of indexing arrays that are broadcastable against each other to result in a higher-dimensional combinations of indices. So, when that tuple is used for indexing into the input array, would give us the same higher-dimensional array. Hence, to make a selection based on two `1D` indexing arrays, it would be -

```
x_indexed = x[np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices)]
```

**B. Assignment**

We can use the same notation for assigning scalar or a broadcastable array into those indexed positions. Hence, the following works for assignments -

```
x[np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices)] = # scalar or broadcastable array
```

#### 2. With `masks`

We can also use boolean arrays/masks with `np.ix_`, similar to how indexing arrays are used. This can be used again to select a block off the input array and also for assignments into it.

**A. Selection**

Thus, with `row_mask` and `col_mask` boolean arrays as the masks for row and column selections respectively, we can use the following for selections -

```
x[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)]
```

**B. Assignment**

And the following works for assignments -

```
x[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)] = # scalar or broadcastable array
```

---

#### Sample Runs

**1. Using `np.ix_` with `indexing-arrays`**

Input array and indexing arrays -

```
In [221]: x
Out[221]: 
array([[17, 39, 88, 14, 73, 58, 17, 78],
       [88, 92, 46, 67, 44, 81, 17, 67],
       [31, 70, 47, 90, 52, 15, 24, 22],
       [19, 59, 98, 19, 52, 95, 88, 65],
       [85, 76, 56, 72, 43, 79, 53, 37],
       [74, 46, 95, 27, 81, 97, 93, 69],
       [49, 46, 12, 83, 15, 63, 20, 79]])

In [222]: row_indices
Out[222]: [4, 2, 5, 4, 1]

In [223]: col_indices
Out[223]: [1, 2]
```

Tuple of indexing arrays with `np.ix_` -

```
In [224]: np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices) # Broadcasting of indices
Out[224]: 
(array([[4],
        [2],
        [5],
        [4],
        [1]]), array([[1, 2]]))
```

Make selections -

```
In [225]: x[np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices)]
Out[225]: 
array([[76, 56],
       [70, 47],
       [46, 95],
       [76, 56],
       [92, 46]])
```

As [suggested by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607818/index-a-2d-numpy-array-with-2-lists-of-indices#comment58900519_35608029), this is in effect same as performing *old-school* broadcasting with a 2D array version of `row_indices` that has its elements/indices *sent* to `axis=0` and thus creating a singleton dimension at `axis=1` and thus allowing broadcasting with `col_indices`. Thus, we would have an alternative solution like so -

```
In [227]: x[np.asarray(row_indices)[:,None],col_indices]
Out[227]: 
array([[76, 56],
       [70, 47],
       [46, 95],
       [76, 56],
       [92, 46]])
```

As discussed earlier, for the assignments, we simply do so.

Row, col indexing arrays -

```
In [36]: row_indices = [1, 4]

In [37]: col_indices = [1, 3]
```

Make assignments with scalar -

```
In [38]: x[np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices)] = -1

In [39]: x
Out[39]: 
array([[17, 39, 88, 14, 73, 58, 17, 78],
       [88, -1, 46, -1, 44, 81, 17, 67],
       [31, 70, 47, 90, 52, 15, 24, 22],
       [19, 59, 98, 19, 52, 95, 88, 65],
       [85, -1, 56, -1, 43, 79, 53, 37],
       [74, 46, 95, 27, 81, 97, 93, 69],
       [49, 46, 12, 83, 15, 63, 20, 79]])
```

Make assignments with 2D block(broadcastable array) -

```
In [40]: rand_arr = -np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)

In [41]: x[np.ix_(row_indices,col_indices)] = rand_arr

In [42]: x
Out[42]: 
array([[17, 39, 88, 14, 73, 58, 17, 78],
       [88,  0, 46, -1, 44, 81, 17, 67],
       [31, 70, 47, 90, 52, 15, 24, 22],
       [19, 59, 98, 19, 52, 95, 88, 65],
       [85, -2, 56, -3, 43, 79, 53, 37],
       [74, 46, 95, 27, 81, 97, 93, 69],
       [49, 46, 12, 83, 15, 63, 20, 79]])
```

**2. Using `np.ix_` with `masks`**

Input array -

```
In [19]: x
Out[19]: 
array([[17, 39, 88, 14, 73, 58, 17, 78],
       [88, 92, 46, 67, 44, 81, 17, 67],
       [31, 70, 47, 90, 52, 15, 24, 22],
       [19, 59, 98, 19, 52, 95, 88, 65],
       [85, 76, 56, 72, 43, 79, 53, 37],
       [74, 46, 95, 27, 81, 97, 93, 69],
       [49, 46, 12, 83, 15, 63, 20, 79]])
```

Input row, col masks -

```
In [20]: row_mask = np.array([0,1,1,0,0,1,0],dtype=bool)

In [21]: col_mask = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],dtype=bool)
```

Make selections -

```
In [22]: x[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)]
Out[22]: 
array([[88, 46, 44, 81],
       [31, 47, 52, 15],
       [74, 95, 81, 97]])
```

Make assignments with scalar -

```
In [23]: x[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)] = -1

In [24]: x
Out[24]: 
array([[17, 39, 88, 14, 73, 58, 17, 78],
       [-1, 92, -1, 67, -1, -1, 17, 67],
       [-1, 70, -1, 90, -1, -1, 24, 22],
       [19, 59, 98, 19, 52, 95, 88, 65],
       [85, 76, 56, 72, 43, 79, 53, 37],
       [-1, 46, -1, 27, -1, -1, 93, 69],
       [49, 46, 12, 83, 15, 63, 20, 79]])
```

Make assignments with 2D block(broadcastable array) -

```
In [25]: rand_arr = -np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [26]: x[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)] = rand_arr

In [27]: x
Out[27]: 
array([[ 17,  39,  88,  14,  73,  58,  17,  78],
       [  0,  92,  -1,  67,  -2,  -3,  17,  67],
       [ -4,  70,  -5,  90,  -6,  -7,  24,  22],
       [ 19,  59,  98,  19,  52,  95,  88,  65],
       [ 85,  76,  56,  72,  43,  79,  53,  37],
       [ -8,  46,  -9,  27, -10, -11,  93,  69],
       [ 49,  46,  12,  83,  15,  63,  20,  79]])
```

Comment: Ah, so if I take the transpose of `row_indices`, should be the same?

Answer (score 12):

What about:

```
x[row_indices][:,col_indices]
```

For example,

```
x = np.random.random_integers(0,5,(5,5))
## array([[4, 3, 2, 5, 0],
##        [0, 3, 1, 4, 2],
##        [4, 2, 0, 0, 3],
##        [4, 5, 5, 5, 0],
##        [1, 1, 5, 0, 2]])

row_indices = [4,2]
col_indices = [1,2]
x[row_indices][:,col_indices]
## array([[1, 5],
##        [2, 0]])
```

Comment: This is fine for fetch, but fails for assignment.  The row index makes a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj both make a copy because of advanced indexing, right?

Comment: @wedran, with one layer of indexing, `x[[1,2,3]] = 2`, the distinction between view and copy doesn't matter (`x.__setitem__(..., 2)`.  It's when you use sequential indexing that you have to pay attention to that issue.  Then the `__setitem__` modifies the first `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random_integers(0,5,(4,4))
x
array([[5, 3, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 0, 0],
       [1, 4, 5, 3],
       [0, 4, 3, 4]])

# This indexes the elements 1,1 and 2,2 and 3,3
indexes = (np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3]))
x[indexes]
# returns array([3, 5, 4])
```

Notice that numpy has very different rules depending on what kind of indexes you use. So indexing several elements should be by a `tuple` of `np.ndarray` (see [indexing manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)).

So you need only to convert your `list` to `np.ndarray` and it should work as expected.

Comment: when elements of "indexes" tuple are of different size, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @ShihabShahriar What would different sizes indicate? That you have partial indices? It seems like you have a different question, if that's the case please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to do one of the following (equlvalent) operations:

```
x_does_work = x[row_indices,:][:,col_indices]
x_does_work = x[:,col_indices][row_indices,:]
```

This will actually create a subset of `x` with only the selected rows, then select the columns from that, or vice versa in the second case. The first case can be thought of as

```
x_does_work = (x[row_indices,:])[:,col_indices]
```

Comment: I like how explicit this is.