# Python: fast subscription of the elements in 2D array that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new in Python and my question might be too obvious, but I did not find a sufficiently good answer.

Suppose I have a 2D array `a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`. How can I subscribe those elements that satisfy a condition? Suppose, I want to increase by one those elements of `a` that are greater than 3. In Matlab, I would do it in 1 line:
`a(a>3)=a(a>3)+1.` What about Python?
The result should be `[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]`.

I am aware that there are functions that can return the indeces I need, like `np.where`. I am also aware that there is a way of [indexing 2D array with two 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607818/index-a-2d-numpy-array-with-2-lists-of-indices). I was not able to combine those together.

Of course, I am able to do it with for loop. I am interested, is there a convenient Matlab-like way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know how boolean indexing works then just an in-place addition is all you need to do:

```
In [6]: a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [7]: a[a>3] += 1  # roughly equal to a = a[a>3] + 1

In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing that confused me when I tried this, was the immediate output that didn't look like a 2D array. But when I subsequently called `a`,  it was displayed correctly

Comment: In MATLAB `a(a>4)` displays a column vector; in `numpy` `a[a>4]` is 1d.  Because of the (potentially) ragged nature of boolean indexing, it can't return a 2d shape.

Comment: What do you mean by `# roughly equal to a = a[a>3] + 1` ? It is not exactly the same?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Same functionality but in slightly different ways. The in-place version changes the items in-place while the second one creates a new array in the fly and then reassigns it to the array.