# Pythonic way of retrieving elements of 2D array by indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Say I have this array of data

```
data = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['x', 'y', 'z', 'zz']])
```

and these indices, each "pair" corresponding to one cell in the data matrix

```
indices = np.asarray([[0, 0], [3, 0], [2, 2], [3, 2]])
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from the specified cells. I can do this via:

```
searched_data = []
for x, y in coords:
    searched_data.append(data[y][x])
```

**Is there a more pythonic or more numpy-ish variation where I can do this in one line by fancy array indexing or something?**

I tried (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607818/index-a-2d-numpy-array-with-2-lists-of-indices)):

```
x_indexed1 = data[indices[:, 1]][:,[indices[:, 0]]]
```

but this gives me

```
[[['1' '4' '3' '4']]

 [['1' '4' '3' '4']]

 [['A' 'D' 'C' 'D']]

 [['A' 'D' 'C' 'D']]]
```

and this

```
x_indexed = data[np.ix_(indices[:, 1],indices[:, 0])]
```

which gives

```
[['1' '4' '3' '4']
 ['1' '4' '3' '4']
 ['A' 'D' 'C' 'D']
 ['A' 'D' 'C' 'D']]
```

Comment: How about `data[indices[:, 1], indices[:,0]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but when you want to index into a `numpy.ndarray` with aligned indices like that, **don't use `[][]`**. Use a *tuple* to do multidimensional indexing:

```
>>> data[indices[:, 1], indices[:,0]]
array(['1', '4', 'C', 'D'], dtype='<U21')
```

To make it more clear:

```
>>> ys = indices[:, 1]
>>> xs = indices[:, 0]
>>> data[ys, xs]
array(['1', '4', 'C', 'D'], dtype='<U21')
```

Your first attempt was something like this:

```
>>> data[ys][:,[xs]]
array([[['1', '4', '3', '4']],

       [['1', '4', '3', '4']],

       [['A', 'D', 'C', 'D']],

       [['A', 'D', 'C', 'D']]], dtype='<U21')
```

So, breaking that down, "partial indexing" assumes a full slice `:` in the dimensions you left out, so for you `data[ys, :]` which selects these rows:

```
>>> data[ys]
array([['1', '2', '3', '4'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']], dtype='<U21')
```

And *that's* what you indexed with `[:, [xs]]`, which basically selects all rows and those xs's columns, which you wrapped in a list, which basically unsqueezes a dimension:

```
>>> data[ys][...,[xs]]
array([[['1', '4', '3', '4']],

       [['1', '4', '3', '4']],

       [['A', 'D', 'C', 'D']],

       [['A', 'D', 'C', 'D']]], dtype='<U21')
```